# App Script My Executions Entries Delayed/Missing

Tags: debugging, logging, google-apps-script, server-error

Recently, I've been having issues with My Executions having delays in adding the execution entries.

The app script on the Google Sheet will run successfully (based on output), but there is no entry in the execution logs or the entry is delayed (10+ minutes).

More worrisome, today I received an automatically generated email with a script error:

> "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

But there was no corresponding entry in executions.

I've tried checking View/Stackdriver Logging, View/Stackdriver Error Reporting - which both go to the Apps Script Dashboard. And I've played with the filters, but the errors do not appear.

Comment: Is that the complete error?  Do you know what script it is? Does the script have Logger.log() or console.log() 's ?

Comment: Does this happen for all scripts or just for a specific one? If it's just this one, could you share a sanitized copy of this script? Also, does it happen to different accounts?

Comment: @Cooper That is the complete error. The email tells me the script. The script has console.log, but not Logger.log.

Comment: @Lamblichus The delay in updating the executions happens on multiple scripts on a single account. I can't share the script, but uses on change events in a Google Sheet and URL fetch to connect to external APIs.

Comment: Well if you can't share script and you don't have any more information than that from the error then you're just going to have to start by removing sections of code until the problem goes away and replace back until it returns to  try to isolate where the problem is and then be familiar enough with the code to see what the problem is

Comment: @Cooper I appreciate the impossibility in trying to debug code that can't be shared. But my concern is more about the executions logger being really slow. Recently, executions is getting a bunch of unknown status and delayed entries. The code is still working fine and immediately, but executions takes 10-15 minutes to take note of that. Is there any way to report on executions server status or check my quota or similar?

Comment: The Logger.log() and console.log now appear in the view executions window.

Comment: I am experiencing the logs in the "view executions" window being slow to appear or not appearing as well.  It is a script I am running repeatedly (because it keeps timing out!) and up until yesterday the logs showed up immediately. Now they are unpredictable. I have not edited the script since I first started running it so I don't know what has changed to prevent the logs from appearing. Very annoying.

Comment: I have been seeing the exact same thing for at least a couple of weeks now.  I use Google Apps Script extensively for the last 18 months.  I have not seen this issue (at least as much) until recently.  Now it is prevalent.  It happens with multiple scripts.  

The "My Executions" (or even going through the Project and then clicking on Project Details menu - Executions) will often be delayed and sometimes never show the execution.

This is with a paid G Suite Business account.  Extremely frustrating!

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue, at least with respect to entries not appearing in "My Executions". This has happened to me multiple times over the past 2 weeks. I haven't received any emails about it, though. Did you figure out a resolution?