# Problem with google.script.run in custom HTML dialog in G Suite account (but not personal Google account)

Tags: html, scripting, permissions, modal-dialog, gsuite-addons

To diagnose the problem using google.script.run in a custom HTML dialog, I ran Google’s example script and HTML code for dialog boxes in both my personal and G Suite accounts. Here is Google's example: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication. The code is shown below.

- In my personal account, the code worked perfectly. The custom HTML dialog popped up and the function doSomething created log output.
- In my G Suite account, the function doSomething did not run at all. I tried playing with settings, testing as an add-on, publishing to the web, and more, but I could not make the Google's sample code work. I spent an hour on the chat session with Google support.

My guess: I am missing a few authorization and/or settings steps in my G Suite account. Please help! I am new to the G Suite AddOn Marketplace, and would appreciate very specific instructions for next steps. I want to make sure my real script works on my  G suite account before submitting it for review. I would like to use custom dialog boxes so that I can collect user input in multiple fields.

Here is a link for a document with screen shot images of my authorization and execution windows. I did NOT get the expected "This app isn't verified" warning in my G Suite account. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IiXmPE7zB1E-s_Uzzhmc0ggOCkz3qqcy1cqZrezkgSg/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the google script code:

```
 // code.gs
 // Use this code for Google Docs, Slides, Forms, or Sheets.
 function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
     .createMenu('Dialog')
  .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
  .addToUi();
}

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}

function doSomething(){   // I added from second step of example
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
   var cell1 = sheet.getRange("A1");
   cell1.setValue("did something");
   Logger.log("did something")
};
```

Here is the HTML code for the file Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>"
   <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
        </head>
        <body>
         Hello, World!

     <script>
     google.script.run.doSomething();
     </script>

        <input type="button" value="Close"
            onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
      </body>
    </html>
```

Similar question posed by: [Google Apps Script - HTML service not working properly only on G-suite accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698272/google-apps-script-html-service-not-working-properly-only-on-g-suite-accounts)

Comment: I could not reproduce this problem, even with a G Suite account. In any case, it might just be a problem of the logging itself (recently the was [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484912) about logging delayed. I'd suggest you to use [Stackdriver logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#using_stackdriver_logging), which is kept for more time than regular logging. Finally, it's normal that you don't get a `This app isn’t verified` in G Suite, as you can see in [this table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#applicability).

Comment: Thanks. I am using Stackdriver logging, and the issue is not the log delay. I also tried fancier doSomething functions that placed values in a cell in the sheet - these worked in my personal account but not in my G Suite account. I was expecting to get a 'This app isn't verified' - I did get it in my personal account, but I did NOT get it in my G Suite account. I think the key is that you were not able to reproduce it in your G Suite account. There must be something wrong with my G Suite account setup.  I do not know what G Suite settings I need to fix. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear - thanks to feedback from lamblichus.

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong. Since I cannot reproduce this, my guess is that the problem is related to your G Suite account. Have you been able to reproduce this in another account from your G Suite domain? I don't think there are G Suite settings that can specifically restrict this, but you could check the restrictions that are set for your account, following [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227).

Comment: Thanks Iamlichus. I have a one-person G suite account, which is why your verification that it worked on your G Suite account was so helpful. I have tried to pick the most open G Suite settings  (all of these settings have been in place for more than 24 hours): (1) Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps, (2) Trust internal, domain-owned apps, (3) Allow unrestricted access to all 11 Google services, (4) Allow DTB Tools trusted access. I purchased my account through a third-party provided who is now incommunicado. I will work on my personal account until this is straightened out.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you to get in touch with [G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) again.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue: I have a ModalDialog in that modal has a that onchange call google.script.host.doSomethig(); .On server code.gs: function doSomething() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); Logger.log('test'); } it should be simple, but unfortunately don't work. Goolge support don't help with script code.

Answer (score 0):

Did your script created in your personal or your GSuite accout? Please consider that Google Chrome capture as global log in, the account (email) that you use to do the first log in. Google don't mind  if from this logged account you logged in others accounts: Google still continuing considering as global loggin the first one account you logged in. In this way, try to do the first log in with your GSuite accout; I hope this will solve the issue and you can run from all your accounts.

(thanks for Hujie Wang's replied to question/60438751/ : that helped me undertood this issue and solve it for my project)